# Xamarin Forms FAB Crashes

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, floating-action-button

Hi i am trying to create a simple FAB on my Xamarin.Forms Application. I am using [FAB.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FAB.Forms) Nuget Package to achieve this (the newest pre-release).

[I am following this example](http://xamarintr.com/Blog/ArticleID/148/Xamarin-Forms-Floating-Action-Button-Kullan%C4%B1m%C4%B1#prettyPhoto)

So this is the the xaml code that should work, but does not for some reason:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LoginSystem.Views.DailyPage"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:LoginSystem.ViewModels"
             xmlns:fab='clr-namespace:FAB.Forms;assembly=FAB.Forms'
             BackgroundColor="Azure" 
             Title="Daily-Stats">

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <RelativeLayout>

            <!--<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Welcome your Daily-Stats!" TextColor="Blue" FontSize="Large"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,50" />
                <Label Text="Page Under Construction" TextColor="Yellow" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,80" />
            </StackLayout>-->

            <ContentView
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1}">

                <ListView x:Name="List" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextCell TextColor="Gray" Text="{Binding .}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </ContentView>

            <fab:FloatingActionButton
                Source="drawable/Add"
                Size="Normal"
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=-75}"         
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1, Constant=-75}"
            />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The app just crashed for whatever reason.

This is the .cs file for the above xaml:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using LoginSystem.Models;
using LoginSystem.ViewModels;
using FAB.Forms;

namespace LoginSystem.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class DailyPage : ContentPage
    {
        public DailyPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var items = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                items.Add(string.Format("Abbas {0}", i));
            }

            this.List.ItemsSource = items;


            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            //BindingContext = new DailyPage_vm();
        }

        public DailyPage(string email, string password)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            this.BindingContext = new DailyPage_vm(email, password);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried making this work on the Old already release Nuget, but no luck.

Comment: Is there an exception thrown? Troubleshooting this issue will be much easier if you include information from the crash.

Comment: I use a try catch inside the constructor, but it doesn't catch any inside. I dont think so that the exception arises outside of it

Comment: I use your code and it works fine, maybe the problem happened in other place?

Comment: Well the thing is, when i comment out the FAB part, my program does not crash; And so i assume it should be in it ? But if you are saying that my code works perfectly on your project, then i am compelled to think you are right.